# AngularJS: use sub-object attribute as ng-model

Tags: c#, javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown which is bound to an object user with the following structure:

```
{
  userId:1,
  userLogin:"test",
  locale: { localeCode:"en-US" }
}
```

This structure comes directly from a C# model class where User and Locale are two classes linked as an association (User has one Locale).

So I would like to define the following dropdown without doing any custom logic like serializing the objects in a special way, or adding $watch to a "UI" attribute so I can update locale.localeCode in the background.

```
<select id="dropLocale" required="required" addempty="true" 
        ng-model="user.locale.localeCode" 
        ng-options="i.localeCode as i.localeCode for i in localeList"></select>
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data structure is like this

```
$scope.localeList = [{
    userId: 1,
    userLogin: "test",
    locale: {
        localeCode: "en-US"
    }
}, {
    userId: 2,
    userLogin: "test2",
    locale: {
        localeCode: "de"
    }
}];
```

I think you missed the level `locale`, try this

```
ng-options="i.locale.localeCode as i.locale.localeCode for i in localeList"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question was to verify the model syntax, not the options.